# Script that does hide/show on DIV and displays selected Block

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a page which has 6 block menu choices and when you click one (e.g. '4') it shows block 4 content in a DIV opposite and will show the block as selected with an arrow.

When you click another block (e.g. '1') it will unselect 4 and then select 1 displaying block 1's content in the DIV.

I'm looking for the best script to do this in JS or jQuery. I'm guessing I could build the blocks as a listed menu and when selected, the CSS will display an image with the arrow.

Thanks

*Update: Here's a mockup of what it will look like:*

[image]

Comment: I think you've answered your own question there.

Comment: just create a jq function that adds a class to the clicked block, in that class you have to define the image as background

Comment: Since you're essentially asking for a solution you'll do better to provide the work you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option instead of building yourself or jQueryUI tabs, I would prefer jQuery Tools Tabs:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/

They can be easily customized to your situation with some CSS adjustments:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/skins.html

(just use some floats and width changes here to get what you're asking for, where XXX+YYY == width of wrapper)

```
#panes     { width:XXXpx; float:right; }
#nav       { width:YYYpx; }
#nav ul    { width:YYYpx; float:left; margin:0; padding:0; }
#nav ul li { width:YYYpx; display:block; margin:0; padding:0; } /* no float! */
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really well implemented in jQuery UI, which has a "tabs" feature.

You could use jQuery UI Tabs and opt to put the selectable options either along the top or along the side and it would behave just like you say you need.

http://jqueryui.com/

Demo of tabs is here...

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/